# Ошибка Gradle при создании нового проекта в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

Ставлю Android Studio на новый пк. При создании нового проекта выходит ошибка. Прокси я прописал. Сам градл версии 4.1
Кто нибудь сталкивался?

Gradle sync failed: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"

Comment: а с параметром `-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""` что говорит?

Comment: Подскажите, где этот параметр в JDK 9. Я нашел решение на английском тоже с этим параметром. Но в java я не могу его найти

Comment: `jdk1.9jre/lib/net.properties` тут должен быть

Comment: отпишусь , все помогло . Спасибо. только просто -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=   без кавычек